# About nodejs server.listen()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I just started to learn about nodejs servers and websockets.
Said I have this server written in javascript using socket.io and express.

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Is there any difference between:

```
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("listening port " + port);
});
```

and

```
server.listen(port);
console.log("listening port " + port);
```

Apparently they work the same.

So what actually server.listen() do?

Comment: First example has callback function another doesn't

Comment: So is a property of javascript functions in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs for `server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback):

> This function is asynchronous. When the server has been bound, 'listening' event will be emitted.

It uses a callback because the log statement inside the callback is a confirmation that the port has been bound.

> Apparently they work the same.

Incorrect. If you log outside of the callback, sure, it'll still log the port number, but this happens in parallel of the actual bounding of the port, and you don't know whether or not it was successful.

Comment: So in the second case it's possible that even if it's not actually listening it will show the console log?

Comment: @AeonZh yes that's true, it may also show the console log before the server is listening. To give you an example in the more familiar area of promises, you wouldn't expect the `result` variable below to contain the result when the console log is called.
`let result; 
fetch('www.google.com').then(response => { result = response; }); console.log('the response is ' + response');`